# Choosing an output directory for MoviePy

Tags: python, moviepy, python-os

So I'm walking a directory that has clips that need to be concatenated. 
I'm having a problem where my output (final_clip) is being written to the directory where the script is stored. How can I change this? 
I looked in the documentation but couldn't find anything.

```
for count, file in enumerate(os.listdir(r"Z:/channel/clips to use/")):
    clip1 = VideoFileClip(r"Z:/channel/resources/comp1.avi")
    clip2 = VideoFileClip(r"Z:/channel/clips to use/"+file)
    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2])
    final_clip.write_videofile("done"+file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `os.chdir(path)` to navigate to the desired directory and then perform write operation or you can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to concatenate path